# How to extract key-value data from a string containing multiple cookies?

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies

Does anyone have an idea for a regex that can match multiple cookies (name, value pairs, combined by '=' and separated by '; ') in a string. With my design I can only match one cookie so far.

```
^(?<cookie>(?<name>.+[^;])=(?<value>.*[^;])(;\s*)?)+$
```

I would like to respect all special characters that cookies can contain. I'd like to use a regex and not rely on split and other functions provided by js.

Thank you very much,

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I slightly tweaked you regex to this: `/(?<cookie>(?<name>[^=]+)=(?<value>[^;]+);\s*)/gm`

For a test string: "name1=value1;name2=value2;"
This produces the matches:

```
match1: name1=value1;
cookie: name1=value1;
name: name1
value: value1

match2: name2=value2;
cookie: name2=value2;
name: name2
value: value2
```

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/CNZqnj/2

EDIT: 
Made changes according to user 'The Fourth Bird's suggestions in the comment.

Comment: You can omit the non greedy repeating of the outer group `(?<cookie>(?<name>[^=]+)=(?<value>[^;]+);)` :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird you are right, since the 'g' flag is enabled the outer non greedy match can be removed. I have updated the answer. Thanks for the suggestion.